# C++Builder How do you use the debugger to look at string in String items in a structure?

Tags: c++builder

I am trying to figure out how to use the watch/inspect/etc.. options in debugging the value in a `String` field of a `struct` pointer.  It will show the name but just gives me an address of the string (not the buffer with the string).

If I use `OuputDebugStringW` the events window still shows ?? instead of the characters.  If I move it to a local variable outside of the structure then I can hover the mouse over it to see the foreign characters.

??

Comment: You should show us your code.  There could be a number of things going on.  Are you convinced the field contains printable characters?  How do you know?

Comment: `String localvar=structname.Varname;`  then I can hover over the localvar are see the foreign characters, `OutputDebugStringW(localvar.c_str());` shows ?? ?? (there are 4 foreign chars) in the events window.

Comment: `OutputDebugStringW` just converts to ASCII and calls `OutputDebugStringA`, because the kernel debug log is only in ASCII.

Comment: @TimRoberts debuggers can opt-in to receive Unicode text from `OutputDebugStringW()` without it being converted to ASCII. This is explained in [`OutputDebugStringW()`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw). I would have expected C++Builder's debugger to do this, given that `UnicodeString` has been around for almost 15 years now.

Comment: @user3161924 which version of C++Builder are you using? Can you provide a code snippet showing the `struct`'s declaration how it is being populated? And also, can you provide screenshots of what you see in the debugger?

Comment: @TimRoberts I use it all the time with Visual Studio for years - I guess limitation of the C++ Builder.